# Git Practice for Separate "Demo" site with dummy content

Tags: git, github, production-environment, staging, demo

I am currently getting ready for my first ever release of a saas product. I am having hard time deciding whether I should keep my customer onboarding "demo" site (with some dummy content) seperate from live production site. So at this point, I am thinking adopting "demo.mysite.com", "mysite.com". Demo site needs to showcase all features of main product as close as possible. I am going to seed the "demo" site with some dummy content.

I don't have a developer team, it's only me at this point.

My work flow would be:

1. Step1: Pull latest code from master(live)
2. Step2: Work locally on a feature
3. Step3: Push it to "staging.mysite.com"
4. Step4: if all is good with staging, push it to demo site and live production site.

Repeat as necessary.

Is this a proper workflow? Should I be thinking about having different branches for all sites? Then I can't figure out how I would keep all of them upto date with the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should implement a standard workflow of dividing the repos from Local> QA>staging then Production so that when you expand into a bigger team the workflow won't be messy and confusing. 
and it will be easy to test on different environments and will make it easy to see where the problem is at before you mage and cause more problems for yourself.

"The Development, Staging, and Production Model. ... No actual code development should ever take place on a staging server—only minor tweaking of OS parameters or application settings. The staging server is the last step before the application is ready for deployment to a production server."

Ref:
https://www.itprotoday.com/devops-and-software-development/development-staging-and-production-model